# Ao editar a pergunta fica com mais do que os 30000 carateres permitidos

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edição

Esta pergunta [Sistema de soma com checkbox não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103022/sistema-de-soma-com-checkbox-n%C3%A3o-funciona) tem a maioria código sem formatação e ao editar e tentar colocar o código bem formatado deparei-me com um problema o corpo da mensagem ultrapassa os 30000 carateres permitidos:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O que se deve fazer nesta situação?

Comment: A primeira coisa que pensei sem ver a pergunta que você tentou editar: Deve ter muito código desnecessário.

Comment: Relacionado: [Limite de linhas de código que podem ser postadas em uma pergunta/resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1301/91)

Comment: @emanuelsn mas e qual escolher?

Comment: Finalmente uma pergunta que é, *por definição*, ampla demais...

Answer (score 3):

Fazer exatamente o que você já estava fazendo, só que com muito mais profundidade.

Você já está *editando* a pergunta, então tem todo o poder do mundo pra resolver o problema do excesso de caracteres. Só vai ser necessário uma edição bem mais significativa que apenas a formatação.

Revise o texto da pergunta. Ele está muito longo? Há alguma parte desnecessária? Tem algo que pode ser reescrito de maneira mais concisa?

O mesmo vale para o código. O que pode sair?  O que é irrelevante?

30000 caracteres é bastante coisa. Certamente a pergunta pode ser reescrita, sem perda de contexto, dentro desse limite.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, até passei o código todo para eliminar espaços, mas a única solução é mesmo apagar código, mas qual? Optei por deixar um comentário ao AP.

Comment: Agora com o comentário do AP na resposta poderia apagar o código que está após o snippet.